# REST: Why use logical URIs?

Tags: api, rest, uri

Other than readability, why would you use logical URIs?

Surely sending a GET request to `/users` (to get all users) is the same as `/users.php`

Surely sending POST to `/users/dave` with some data to update Dave is the same as `/users.php?name=dave&phone=1234`

You decide what to do based on the HTTP method, and then you pull apart the URI string anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logical URIs decouple client code from the implementation details of the server-side code.  In your `/users.php` example, `.php` is an implementation detail.  If I publish that URI as an endpoint, clients will depend on that specific PHP script.  I won't be able to switch to a Java or .NET implementation without changing client code.  (Or I'd have to do some really unsavory remappings on the server.)